# What distinguishes inverses in Category Theory?

Tags: category-theory, inverse

I've seen the following definition of isomorphism in a few places now (notably in Aluffi's '[Algebra: Chapter 0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821847813)'):

**Definition:** A morphism $\mathcal{f} \in \operatorname{Hom}_C(A, B)$ is an *isomorphism* if it has a (two-sided) inverse under composition: that is, if $\exists\mathcal{g}\in\operatorname{Hom}_C(B, A)$ such that $$\mathcal{gf}=id_A,\mathcal{fg}=id_B$$

I sense that my intuition here is wrong on some level, but I was under the impression that the premise of Category Theory is that the mathematical truth of things should reveal itself through structure and composition and not through any notational convention, however I can't seem to square that with this definition.

If structure is everything then why are $\mathcal{f}$ and $\mathcal{g}$ are singled out in this definition? Surely I could take any morphism from $\operatorname{Hom}_C(A, B)$ and compose it with a morphism from $\operatorname{Hom}_C(B, A)$ to get a morphism which takes me on a journey from $A$ to $A$ - i.e. something structurally equivalent to $id_A$.

So what's special about $\mathcal{f}$ and $\mathcal{g}$? How is equivalence with $id_A$ determined?

Comment: Suppose that $A$ is $\{0,1,2\}$, $B$ is $\{0\}$, $f$ is the morphism that takes everything to $0$, and $g$ is the morphism that takes $0$ to $0$. Is $gf$ equivalent to $id_A$?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are not special. They are variables. Also, not every morphism $A \to A$ is "equivalent" to $\textrm{id}_A$ in any reasonable sense.

Comment: This is a definition. It isn’t notation. You can prove from the definition that if $f$ is an isomorphism, that $g$ is unique and also and also an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A category is more than just a bunch of objects and a bunch of morphisms between them: it's a bunch of objects, a bunch of morphisms, **and** a composition operation (satisfying a couple basic properties). Part of the philosophy of category theory is that it's often a good idea, given a particular category of interest, to forget the "additional context" and just look at the category on its own, but the composition operation is *a piece of* that "on its own"-ness. Indeed, it's absolutely crucial: without composition, there's very little point to a category at all.

Morphisms with the same source and target may nonetheless be extremely different in terms of how they interact with the composition function. In particular, given an object $A$ there is *exactly one* $\alpha\in Hom(A,A)$ with the property that for every $\beta\in Hom(A,A)$ we have $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha=\beta$; note that this defining property is just about the category on its own, not about any of the "additional context" that might be present. So picking out the identity arrow - and consequently the inversehood relationship - is **not** taking us beyond the "category-only" perspective.

Comment: So, essentially, the problem is that I'm looking at a category as if it were just a $DAG$ - something that you could draw on a piece of paper and see the complete structure of - when in fact such a representation would miss half of the information?

That still leaves me lacking an intuitive sense of what that composition dimension looks like, but this at least answers what I asked, so I'll mark it as such. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after mulling this over for a few hours I believe I've finally cleared up my confusion, and think it might be worth leaving a record of the intuition I came to, namely:

***It's all about the journey***

It's tempting to focus on the fact that $\mathcal{g}\space\circ\space\mathcal{f}$ takes you from $A$ and brings you back to $A$, but that doesn't mean that you're back to where you started; in Category Theory such a composition would actually leave you in something akin to a future-version of $A$ - a version that remembers the history of where you came from. This 'history' is not something you can represent well in a picture (given that you're free to traverse $\mathcal{g}\space\circ\space\mathcal{f}$ infinitely many times), so we draw the minimum and express the rest with composition rules.

As an example, if $\mathcal{f}$ means *'Get Tattoo'* and $\mathcal{g}$ means *'Have Tattoo Removed'* then in a sense you're 'back to where you started', but that would be a very one-dimensional perspective; in reality you're going to have a scar (and the memory of your time with your inky dragon friend). In this case $\mathcal{g}\space\circ\space\mathcal{f}\ne id_A$.

However, suppose that $\mathcal{f}$ means *'Type Character'* and $\mathcal{g}$ means *'Press Backspace'* then, as long as the word-processing software we're using doesn't save any undo-history, we're free to write $\mathcal{g}\space\circ\space\mathcal{f}= id_A$.

Same diagram (in a sense), but different rules.

So, in short, the diagram isn't enough. The 'objects' in the category are really just way-markers that help guide our journeys. The real information lies in the journeys you take (morphism-composition) and expressions (such as $\mathcal{g}\space\circ\space\mathcal{f}= id_A$) which tell us which journey's are equivalent.

Comment: I'm afraid you have the wrong picture. A category is not some kind of generalised state machine, morphisms are not some kind of generalised state transition. Think instead of, say, data types and functions.

Comment: Thanks, but any chance of elaborating? When you say 'data-type' my mind visualises a single node with multiple versions (e.g. a Bool node having two 'versions' - True and False). I'm failing to see how that differs from my analogy of different points in space-time having multiple versions. The pedagogical purpose of my analogy was to draw the mind towards focusing on the morphisms and not the objects.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "version" but if your analogy is that objects in a category are like points in space-time then you have the wrong picture. Or, rather, you are focusing too much on pictures. A map is not the territory, etc.

Comment: I'm sensing that we're possibly in agreement but differing on language. The issue I was having in the first place (my reason for opening the question) was that I was thinking of things as a map - a map in which equality is established by which things you can connect together. The realisation I was trying to communicate above is that, as you say, it isn't a map, because equality isn't established by anything that's easy to draw.